# Where Like Dependent on User ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like

I have been using a query which checks the users input from a search field and gets the relevant data back. This query is using multiple likes to check various fields (Name, Reference, Order ID etc.).

I noticed that the query is ignoring where it checks the **Users ID** to bring up records from that user only. And instead brings back records from all users. This is the current query:

```
SELECT  ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, ORDER_REF, ORDER_RECNAME 
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE USER_ID = '$userID' AND ORDER_ID LIKE '%$SearchData%' 
    OR ORDER_RECNAME LIKE '%$SearchData%' OR ORDER_REF LIKE '%$SearchData%' 
    OR ORDER_POSTCODE LIKE '%$SearchData%' 
GROUP BY ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, ORDER_REF, ORDER_RECNAME
```

Is there somewhere im simply going wrong? It is using the `Likes` correctly but not the `WHERE USER_ID` part.

Comment: Try this: SELECT 
ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, ORDER_REF, ORDER_RECNAME FROM ORDERS 
WHERE USER_ID = '$userID' AND (ORDER_ID LIKE '%$SearchData%' OR ORDER_RECNAME LIKE '%$SearchData%' OR ORDER_REF LIKE '%$SearchData%' OR ORDER_POSTCODE LIKE '%$SearchData%' )
GROUP BY ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, ORDER_REF, ORDER_RECNAME

Comment: @FlorinSecal Thankyou! Working perfect now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `and` and `or` operators in the where criteria without parentheses and this causes the issue. Encapsulate the `like` operators connected by `or` to apply the user_id restriction to all of them. Remember, `and` operator has higher priority than `or`!

```
USER_ID = '$userID' AND (ORDER_ID LIKE '%$SearchData%' 
OR ORDER_RECNAME LIKE '%$SearchData%' OR ORDER_REF LIKE '%$SearchData%' 
OR ORDER_POSTCODE LIKE '%$SearchData%')
```